# Array not rending correctly into a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array that I am passing down to a child component, where I want all the array elements to render in a list. Not complicated, I've done this a bunch of times, except this time I'm not able to get it to format the way I want.

In my parent, I am filtering through an array of objects in my state, and returning the object that I want:

```
state = {
    activeTab: 0,
    tabs: [
      {
        id: 0,
        icon: <AiFillShopping />,
        label: 'Groceries',
        content: ['grocery list', 'test']
      }, 
      {
        id: 1,
        icon: <FaSchool />,
        label: 'School',
        content: ['school list', 'test']
      }
    ],
    value: '',
  }
```

```
let filteredContent = this.state.tabs.filter((tab, index) => {
      if(index === this.state.activeTab) {
        return tab;
      }
    })
console.log(filteredContent) // logs {id: 0, label: "Groceries", content: Array(2)}
```

Then I'm passing filteredContent to my child, and then in my child I am mapping through the prop to get the content and list the items out as a list:

```
<ul>
   {this.props.content.map(content=> <li>{content.content}</li>)}
</ul>
```

But it's coming out as one list item, with the elements all in one line like this:
"grocery listtest"

I'm sure I just did something stupid, but I've been staring at it for long at this point I could use another pair of eyes.

Comment: What is the content of `this.props.content` before the render function? Is it what you would expect, or is it different?

Comment: @A_A not it's not different, it's the same. It logs {id: 0, label: "Groceries", content: Array(2)}

Comment: @Sphinx it's not literally show the <li> tags, but it's rendering as grocery listtest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `content.content` is an array of renderable content, i.e. strings, it is concatenated for you by React and rendered.

You will want to flatten the nested `content` arrays first, then map them to JSX.

```
<ul>
  {content
    .flatMap((content) => content.content)
    .map((content) => (
      <li key={content}>{content}</li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

```js
function App() {
  const content = [
    {
      id: 0,
      // icon: <AiFillShopping />,
      label: "Groceries",
      content: ["grocery list", "test"]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      // icon: <FaSchool />,
      label: "School",
      content: ["school list", "test"]
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {content
          .flatMap((content) => content.content)
          .map((content) => (
            <li key={content}>{content}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

If you happen to just want a comma separated content list they join the content array.

```
<ul>
  {content.map((content) => (
    <li key={content}>{content.content.join(", ")}</li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

#### Note on filtering

`Array.prototype.filter` callback returns a boolean, ***not*** the element you want in the result array. Your filter code only works by "accident" since returning a `tab` is coerced to a truthy value, and when the index doesn't match you are implicitly returning undefined which is a falsey value. You should just return the result of the condition.

```
const filteredContent = this.state.tabs.filter(
  (tab, index) => index === this.state.activeTab
);
```

Since you are filtering the tabs array and (*presumably*) rendering them then you might not want to use the array index as it isn't intrinsically related to any tab. Using the `tab.id` and storing an active tab id would a better choice since the `id` isn't related to any relative position in the array it'll always be the same per tab object.

Comment: Oh wonderful, this solved my issue! And thanks for the note about the filtering, I'll make sure to apply that